# Hypotenuse using function & Math.sqrt() javascript

Tags: javascript, function, hypotenuse

Hello I am doing this function calculating the hypotenuse. here the code I created so far. I have to use the Math.sqrt() method which is a part of the requirement. 
Once the code is running nothing occurs.
Thanks for your help guys!

```
 function getHeight() {
 var n = 5;
 return = n;
 }
 function getWidth() {
 var n = 12;
 return n;
 }
 function getHypotenuse(height,width) {
 var hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(height*height + width*width);
 return hypotenuse;
 }
 function displayHypotenuse() {
 alert("the hypotenuse is: " + getHypotenuse(getHeight(),getWidth()));
 }
 function init() {
 displayHypotenuse();
 }
 window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Check for errors in your browser's console.  They'll be there, if you look for them.

Comment: this question should be closed because the most trivial of debugging efforts would have shown the syntax error in `return = n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
function getHeight() {
 var n = 5;
 return = n;
 }
```

use

```
function getHeight() {
 var n = 5;
 return n;
 }
```

The issue is with **return = n**